# Checking if a term known, exists on an infinite sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given integer $b$, how to check that $b$ exists in an infinite arithmetic sequence $S_n$, where the difference between two consecutive numbers is $d$ and $S_0 = a$?

That is, there exists a positive integer $i$, such that $S_i = b$?

Is there any formula except brute forcing the solution?

Comment: Can you explain further. For example, $b$ certainly belongs to the infinite AP $b,b+d,b+2d,b+3d,\dots$.

Comment: yeah, sorry. edited. I got real helpful answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $n$ you know that $S_n=S_0+nd$. Thus, $b$ is some $S_n$ if and only if $b=S_0+nd$ for some $n$. That $n$ would have to be

$$n=\frac{b-S_0}d\;,$$

so all you have to do is divide $b-S_0$ by $d$: if the result is a positive integer $n$, then $b=S_n$, and if not, then $b$ is not a term of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

$b$ exists in an arithmetic sequence with difference $d$ iff $ b \equiv S_n \bmod d$ for some (and hence all) $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The nth term in an arithmetic sequence with first term $a_0$ and common difference d is $a_0+ d(n-1)$.  The number b will be in that sequence if and only if $a_0+ d(n-1)= b$ for some **integer** value of n.

For example, if $a_0= 4$ and d= 3, the number 3743 IS in the sequence because solving $3+ 4(n-1)= 3743$ we have $4(n-1)= 4n- 4= 3740$ so $4n= 3744$ and then $n= 3744/4= 936$, an integer.   4395  is NOT in the sequence because if $3+ 4(n-1)= 4395$, $4n- 4= 4392$, $4n= 4395$, $n= 4395/4= 1098.75$ which is not an integer.